# Symfony EventSubscriber: The Page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: symfony, response, symfony4

I have been recently researching EventListeners for the kernal for Symfony4 and I thought I had grasped the basic concept of it but I seem to get a `page isn't redirecting properly` issue with my EventSubscriber.

Essentially I'd like  to do the following logic:

```
if file_exists $file
    redirect to file
else
    carry on as normal
```

Which is how I originally came to `kernel.response`. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class MaintenanceSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if (file_exists('maintenance.flag')) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse('maintenance');
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => 'onKernelResponse'
        );
    }
}
```

this does my logic more or less perfectly, when `maintenance.flag` doesn't exist it carries on the project as expected, but when I `touch maintenance.flag` it gets the infamous Firefox page of `Page isn't redirecting properly`.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something?

I've set up my route:

```
maintenance:
    path: /maintenance
    controller: App\Controller\Maintenance\FlagController::flag
```

which is just a render function - I have a feeling that this could be causing the issue (an endless loop of redirect to `flag()` which then performs the before action?) but I'm not sure how to render my template from the `setResponse()` method

Even with the routing conf commented out, I still get the error. So not 100% sure anymore that it's the `flag()` endless loop theory

Comment: I suspect that this is a cyclic execution of the listener. I would also add a check in your if to check if the current page is maintenance before redirecting again

Comment: @Dimitris I thought that too until I commented out my route stuff - so not sure it is :s

Comment: Adding some debug entries to LoggerInterface will help you pinpoint the issue. And add the check for the redirect anyway. It makes sense to do such a check even if this is not your current issue.

Comment: Handling maintenance mode in symfony is a bad idea as any code error during the maintenance will also break the maintenance page. You can also see https://github.com/lexik/LexikMaintenanceBundle

Comment: @goto do S2 bundles work in S4? I thought bundles were removed/altered in S4 to a point that isn't compatible with S2 modules?

Comment: Sorry, you are right it's only sf2. Still a bad idea to handle this in symfony in my humble opinion ^^

Comment: @goto np just had to double check haha :) and it's mainly for quick updates - for production use only whilst I git pull sorta thing - nothing to major, but I do respect your opinion - it could render my maintenance mode useless if symfony itself breaks haha

Comment: RedirectResponse takes a url as input.  You are only passing the name of a route.  Take a look at FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerTrait::redirectToRoute() to see how to generate the proper url from a route name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right indeed about the endless loop being the issue, adding this conditional to exclude the `/maintenance` url got it to work:

```
if (strpos($event->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), 'maintenance') !== false) {
    return;
}
```